# Use 'net' Node.js module in ReactNative

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I would like to use the [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) Node.js module in a react native mobile app.

I've first create a simple node.js script to test a client/server connection with the following code.

```
const net = require('net');

const client = new net.Socket();
client.connect({ port: 59090, host: process.argv[2] });
client.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString('utf-8'));
});
```

Everything is working fine but when I call this script from a ReactNative app I've the following error:

```
Unable to resolve module `net` from `Client.js`: net could not be found within the project.
```

Why can I not use a node.js library in a react native app ? Are there any alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [react-native-tcp-socket](https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-tcp-socket). This is because you can't use node Net from React Native. Have a read of the README on the link I provided.